# Check if eager-loaded category exists on product

Tags: categories, eager-loading

On my craft commerce project i eager-load categories which belong to a prodcut.

in my product template i do for eager -loading:

```
{% do craft.app.elements.eagerLoadElements(
  className(product),
  [product],
  [
    ['NameOfproductCategory'],
  ]
) %}
```

Before i added this eager-loading i checked if a certain categroy exists in a product to change the sytling:

```
{% if product.NameOfproductCategory.id('9999').exists() %}
    <div class="newproduct">
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

now with this eager-loading i get this error and i dont know how to solve it.

```
Impossible to invoke a method ("id") on an array.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without eager-loading, accessing the categories field will return a [`CategoryQuery`](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v4/craft-elements-db-categoryquery.html) which you can add parameters to and execute with methods like `exists()`. With eager-loading, the categories are already loaded before you access them, so instead of a query you get an [`ElementCollection`](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v4/craft-elements-elementcollection.html).

The element collection has some custom methods to be compatible with element queries, and extends `Illuminate\Support\Collection`, so you can use all the various [collection methods](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections).

You can check if the collection contains a collection with a specific ID like this:

```twig
{% if product.NameOfproductCategory.contains('id', '9999') %}
```

Comment: Thanks! One thing though, it's not `.contains`, but `|contains`. Can you adjust your answer, i cannot.

Comment: @Henrik No, `.contains` is correct. As I said, since you have a [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections), you can call any of it's instance methods. In this case, I'm calling the [`.contains` method](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-contains). You can also use `|contains`, which is the Craft filter of the same name.

Comment: Ah, ok. `.contains` did not work in my case, but `|contains` did. That's why i thought you meant maybe the filter.

Comment: @Henrik If `.contains` doesn't work, that means your categories were not eager-loaded! You can check whether the categories field gives you can `ElementCollection` or a `CategoryQuery` like this: `{% dd product.NameOfProductCategory %}`. If you get an `CategoryQuery`, that means your eager-loading is not working properly. But yes, `|contains` should work with arrays as well as collections, so it's safe to use if you're not sure if the field is eager-loaded or not. If your question is solved, don't forget to mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: thanks! interessting. I used the blitz recommendations to speed up my a site and after i inserted the code in my question, the hint to eager-load my categories are gone and i noticed a huge decrease of db request in the debug toolbar. so i thought i successfully eager-loaded. have to look to that again then.